# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been stuck on this for ages and can't figure out why the error pops up.

```
async function verify(i) {
    try {
        var g = await client.guilds.cache.get("943025185295044608");
        var r = await g.roles.cache.get("943202823217221652");
        var mem = await client.users.cache.get(i)
        
        mem.roles.add(r);
        client.channels.cache.get("944841210462367794").send(`${mem} was verified`)
    } catch (e) {
        client.channels.cache.get("944841210462367794").send(`${mem} was not verified`)
        console.log(g)
        console.log(r)
        console.log(mem)
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

When I console.log it comes up with the variable as defined.
Ive tried doing await but that doesnt work.
Im also working in discord.js v12

Comment: `mem.roles` is `undefined`. Check the content of `mem` if that is what it should be.

Comment: `mem` is a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User). Users don't have `roles`. [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember)s have roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ivar I got my answer
`mem` is a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User). Users don't have roles. [GuildMembers](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember) have roles.
So I changed
`client.users.cache.get(i)`
to
`g.members.cache.get(i)`